# recover whatsapp messages (database folder deleted)

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

**Problem**

I accedently formatted my memory card which had the database folder of whatsapp which had the last backup of my messages .... Now how can I get all my messages back ?? is there an online backup of my messages ?? Is there a way to get the messages back or should I stop searching for solutions since there is no backup in the sd card nor phone ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for you but that isn't possible. Whatsapp only stores message backups locally. The only things on the Whatsapp servers are messages that hasn't been delivered yet. I.E. Skype doesn't backup messages on their servers and they also don't store messages on it which haven't been delivered yet so the 2 contacts have to be online to receive the message. If one of them isn't the message will never be delivered to the other unless they come back online at the same time. It might be usefull to backup your Whatsapp message backups to the cloud. I.E Google Drive.

Have a nice day,

Comment: oh dear GOD ... well thankyou for google drive advice ... i guess thats it ... thanks again for replying