# How do I recover deleted WhatsApp database (msgstore.db.crypt12 files) without backup?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, internal-storage, data-recovery, 7.0-nougat

I accidentally deleted my WhatsApp database folder and have lost all my chat history. How can I restore it?
Deleted from phone's internal storage, Android 7, no root access and no other copy of the folder exists.

I checked out multiple other links, e.g:
[recover whatsapp messages (database folder deleted)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93455/recover-whatsapp-messages-database-folder-deleted) |
[Recover Whats-app database files (.crypt12)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173256/recover-whats-app-database-files-crypt12) |
[How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208106/how-to-recover-a-deleted-file-from-data-partition) etc

...however, the information is old or dealing with rooted devices or dealing with recovery from backups or dealing with SD cards etc none of which work for my situation.

I've also tried Tenorshare UltData, but it can't retrieve .crypt12 files.

Is there a way to recover and restore my databases/chats?

Comment: PS: I'm fine with a rooting solution; if it's one that won't overwrite  the files I'm trying to retrieve.

Comment: if you read the answers you just have linked, you know you can't recover deleted files. take note that crypt files **are** backup files, no need to recover them. the actual whatsapp database is in apps data (one can access without root) https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/2770982

Comment: the app mentioned is a joke, like all such apps. I made simple test, created picture, the app shows it. deleted picture, scanned right after, the app cannot show it anymore.